# Il significato di "quella"

Tags: meaning

Oggi ho letto questo su Facebook:

> In nome del "politicamente corretto", diventò così antidemocratico criticare il bellicismo occidentale od antisemita quello israeliano, fondamentalista o patriarcale invocare il rispetto delle tradizioni e dei luoghi di culto propri ed altrui, sessista e maschilista criticare l'arroganza di certe donne, omofobo quella di certi gay, o razzista quella di certi stranieri, o fascista quella di certi liberali di sinistra e comunista quella di certi liberali di destra. Poi finì che ci guardammo tra di noi e ci scoppiò da ridere, e così tutto quel bel mondo di finzioni ed illusioni semplicemente se ne sparì, sotto una bella risata.

Non capisco il significato di "quella" nelle seguenti frasi: "omofobo quella di certi gay", "razzista quella di certi stranieri", "fascista quella di certi liberali di sinistra e comunista quella di certi liberali di destra".
Inoltre, non capisco perché usa il passato remoto. Non ne dubito la correttezza perché lui di mestiere fa lo scrittore.

Qualcuno mi illumina? Grazie mille.

Comment: Chi è il “lui” che fa lo scrittore?

Comment: È un giornalista di Pisa.

Answer (score 6):

Guarda la frase precedente:

> ...criticare **l'arroganza** di certe donne, omofobo quella di certi gay,
> o razzista quella di certi stranieri, o fascista quella di certi
> liberali di sinistra e comunista quella di certi liberali di destra.

Quindi il "quella" si riferisce sempre all'arroganza.

> ...criticare **l'arroganza** di certe donne, (diventò) omofobo (criticare) quella (l'arroganza) di certi gay, o (diventò) razzista (criticare) quella (l'arroganza) di certi stranieri,...

Per quanto riguarda l'uso del passato remoto, posso solo ipotizzare che il testo sia ambientato nel futuro e stia parlando di ciò che successe nel passato (ossia attualmente) e che presumibilmente portò a certe conseguenze delle quali ha parlato o parlerà nel testo.

Comment: Grazie della preziosa spiegazione. Mi è rimasta un dubbio: è normale nella scrittura e nel parlato omettere "criticare"? Così, sorvolare due tre parole di fila mi aveva creato molta difficoltà nella comprensione. Per quanto riguarda l'uso del passato remoto, rimango in attesa di altre spiegazioni, ed eventualmente chiederò spiegazione all'autore del testo.

Comment: Omette "criticare" perché quello sarebbe il verbo ripetuto, non ha nulla di speciale. Se il verbo fosse stato, ad esempio, "andare", avrebbe potuto omettere quello: "gli piaceva molto andare al cinema, a teatro, allo stadio".

Comment: Ho capito!! Grazie mille.

Comment: Riporto la risposta sua: è un modo retorico: è come se parlassi di un fatto passato, anche se in realtà è attuale. Infatti quando poi scrivo "poi finì che ecc." appare come se quel fatto ad un certo punto fosse finito ed oggi non esistesse più. Dà l'idea di una futura possibilità, come se fosse una previsione, perché tanto appare paradossale un fatto del genere che appare pure difficile che possa davvero durare a lungo.